# Status of file opening in Assembly x8086

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86-16

I'm trying to open a file in my assembly program. Here's the code:

```
openFile    proc
    push ax
    push bx

    mov ax,seg data
    mov ds,ax

    cmp cl,21d
    je  secondToInput

    secondToInput:
    mov al,0    
    mov ah,03dh
    int 021h
    jb  failedOpening
    mov ds:[INPUT],ax
    jmp endOfProc

    ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    failedOpening:
    mov dx,offset FAILEDOPEN
    mov ah,09h
    int 021h
    mov ah,04ch
    int 021h

    ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    endOfProc:
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
openFile    endp
```

Firstly, to clarify the code:

**CL** is set before calling the **openFile** procedure. According to that argument, procedure makes jump to the corresponding block of code and performs it (for know, I have only one jump, as you can see). **DX** is also set in advance, and is an offset of a "string" containing file name, ended with "0", for example: "test.txt",0.

Now, the problem:

I want to know whether file opening ended successfully or not. I've read that if **CF** is set, then it means that there were some problems. The program, however, always jumps to **failedOpening**, no matter if a file really exists or not.

Comment: Better use the jump if the carry flag is set instruction: "jc failedOpening".

Comment: @DirkWolfgangGlomp while that is indeed more readable, the `jb` instruction is the same as `jc`.

Comment: Setting `DS` in your proc is very suspicious. Make sure the `DX` which is set to your filename is from the same segment. Also, check the returned error code in `AX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some little changes to your code to make it work with EMU8086, it is below (**pay attention to the comments added**). You know, maybe the problem is that your program can't find the file, for example, with compiler EMU8086, the files usually have to be in "path\EMU8086\MyBuild", even if you add the full path to your file to open it, sometimes EMU8086 doesn't let you find it unless you store it in "MyBuild". Maybe that's your case (it has happened to me).

```
.stack 100h

.data

filename    db 'test.txt',0
filehandler dw ? 
okopen      db 'open ok$'
failedopen  db 'error open$'

.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

;DATA SEGMENT MUST HAVE BEEN INITIALIZED SINCE THE BEGINNING, OR
;THE NEXT "OFFSET FILENAME" WON'T WORK.
    mov  dx, offset filename 
    call openFile

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.
    mov  ah,7
    int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

;---------------------------------------------------------------------

openFile    proc
    push ax
    push bx

;    mov ax,seg data   ;<======== DON'T INITIALIZE DATA
;    mov ds,ax         ;<======== SEGMENT IN A PROCEDURE.

    cmp cl,21d        
    je  secondToInput

    secondToInput:
;OPEN FILE.
    mov al,0             ;READ ONLY MODE.
    mov ah,03dh          ;SERVICE TO OPEN FILE.
    int 21h
    jb  failedOpening    ;ERROR IF CARRY FLAG.
    mov filehandler, ax  ;IF NO ERROR, NO JUMP. SAVE FILEHANDLER.
;DISPLAY OK MESSAGE.
    mov dx,offset okopen
    mov ah,09h
    int 021h
    jmp endOfProc

    ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------
;DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE.
    failedOpening:
    mov dx,offset FAILEDOPEN
    mov ah,09h
    int 021h
;    mov ah,04ch        ;<======== DON'T END THE PROGRAM
;    int 021h           ;<======== IN A PROCEDURE.

    ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    endOfProc:
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
openFile    endp
```

Don't forget to change the value for variable "filename" ('test.txt') for an existent file.

Comment: Yep, that was a problem with path. Thank you for your help. And also thanks for that tips concerning data init and ending an program.

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

<del>DOS-strings are not zero-terminated but end with a '$'.</del>

Edit: I should have looked at the documentation and seen that `DS:DX = pointer to an ASCIIZ file name`

Your code contains some quirks, for example instead of:

```
mov al,0h
mov ah,03dh
```

Why not write:

```
mov ax,0x3d00
```

Comment: Nope, `int21/3d` does expect a zero terminated string.

Comment: `Pointer to an ASCIIZ file-name`, yeah ok that was clearly my mistake